# Is there line limit in Github Page?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I am using github page Cayman theme.

I have uploaded MD file with size and length of 390 lines (244 sloc)  20.4 KB.

When I check preview changes on Github, there is nothing wrong. 
But when I check my github.io website, there's an error.

There is nothing wrong with text and image until line 107 but after that line, it seems like markdown is not working from there. 
So I am guessing if there is any line and length limit. 
How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You have most likely a syntax error of some kind in your markdown…which you did not show to us.

Comment: @KlausD. I will edit and try to upload my file here.. but when I edit markdown on github and check 'preview changes' there's nothing wrong. In this case, it;s not syntax error is it?

Comment: There is not such limit in GitHub Pages. Pls check your markdown for syntax errors. You can visit this [Site](https://dillinger.io/) to check your markdown file.

Comment: Last I knew, Pages uses a different Markdown parser ([Kramdown](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#kramdown)) than GitHub.com (Commonmark). Most likely the two parsers are handling a syntax error differently. However, more recently, Jekyll (the engine behind Pages) added support for [Commonmark](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#commonmark). According to [this](https://github.com/github/jekyll-commonmark-ghpages), GitHub is currently "testing" Commonmark for GitHub Pages. I'm not sure if you can configure Pages to use it or not, but if so, that may resolve it.

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj Thank you. It seems like ' < ' is not working in GitHub Pages and caused error.

Comment: @Waylan Thank you. It seems like '<' is not working in Pages. So I deleted and it worked

Answer (score 0):

There is no any line limits in GitHub Pages. Markdown Syntax Errors can cause this type of Errors. You can visit the below mentioned Site to check your markdown file.

https://dillinger.io/